# How do programs like LogMeIn work in the aspect of file transfer

Tags: networking, file-upload, file-transfer

I use LogMeIn primarily because most of the time I need to access files from my computer. Lets say that the file that I want to access is in computer A and I am using computer B. If I get a file from computer A that means that that file goes to some server computer X then to computer B?

Another way where I can access a file from my computer is if I install some kind of server in my computer such as WAMP, I open the port in my router so that all traffic that comes in from port 80 goes to computer A and that way when I type my WAN IP address I will be going to my www directoy at computer A. Lastly I will be able to access all files inside my www root directoy.

There are some other times where I have to open ports in my firewall to let this happen. I will like to create a program that would let me access the files in my computer securely. It will make no sense to have all my files inside my www root directory. Moreover do I have to open the port in my router to make this happen. When I send a file from logmein I did not had to open any ports in my router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a connection, you must open a port on one side or the other.  Services like LogMeIn do what you suspect by using a computer in the middle as a proxy.

There's really no need to reinvent the wheel with secure file transfer.  Find yourself some reputable sftp server software, open a port on your router, choose good user names and passwords or even better use public key authentication with a good passphrase, and keep the software up to date.  SSH port forwarding and some scripting can be used if you have a proxy server available, or if you don't have control over the firewall one of your computers is behind.